# PHP XML Reader timing out?

Tags: php, xml, error-handling, timeout, xmlreader

I have the following PHP script for accessing website content for my site:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("x", "x", "x", "x");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE products SET in_stock = 'no'");
$xml = new XMLReader;
$xml->open('compress.zlib://file.xml/compression/gzip/');
while ($xml->read())
{
    if ($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT)
    {
        if ($xml->name == 'merchant')
        {
            $merchant                  = array();
            $merchant['merchant_id']   = $xml->getAttribute('id');
            $merchant['merchant_name'] = $xml->getAttribute('name');
        }
    }
    if ($xml->nodeType == XMLREADER::ELEMENT)
    {
        if ($xml->name == 'prod')
        {
            $prod                  = array();
            $prod['merchant_id']   = $merchant['merchant_id'];
            $prod['merchant_name'] = $merchant['merchant_name'];
            $prod['aw_product_id'] = $xml->getAttribute('id');
            $prod['in_stock']      = $xml->getAttribute('in_stock');
        }
        if ($xml->name == 'name')
        {
            $xml->read();
            $prod['product_name'] = $xml->value;
        }
        if ($xml->name == 'awTrack')
        {
            $xml->read();
            $prod['aw_deep_link'] = $xml->value;
        }
        if ($xml->name == 'awImage')
        {
            $xml->read();
            $prod['aw_image_url'] = $xml->value;
        }
        if ($xml->name == 'buynow')
        {
            $xml->read();
            $prod['search_price'] = $xml->value;
        }
        if ($xml->name == 'rrp')
        {
            $xml->read();
            $prod['rrp_price'] = $xml->value;
        }
        if ($xml->name == 'awCatId')
        {
            $xml->read();
            $prod['category_id'] = $xml->value;
        }
        if ($xml->name == 'awCat')
        {
            $xml->read();
            $prod['category_name'] = $xml->value;
        }
        if ($xml->name == 'awBrandId')
        {
            $xml->read();
            $prod['brand_id'] = $xml->value;
        }
        if ($xml->name == 'brandName')
        {
            $xml->read();
            $prod['brand_name'] = $xml->value;
        }
    }
    if ($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::END_ELEMENT)
    {
        if ($xml->name == 'prod')
        {
            $products[] = $prod;
        }
    }
    if ($xml->nodeType == XMLReader::END_ELEMENT)
    {
        if ($xml->name == 'merchant')
        {
            $merchants[] = $merchant;
        }
    }
}
$i = 0;
foreach ($products as $row)
{
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO products (merchant_id, merchant_name, aw_product_id, in_stock, product_name, aw_deep_link, aw_image_url, search_price, rrp_price, category_id, category_name, brand_id, brand_name) VALUES ('$row[merchant_id]', '$row[merchant_name]', '$row[aw_product_id]', '$row[in_stock]', '$row[product_name]', '$row[aw_deep_link]', '$row[aw_image_url]', '$row[search_price]', '$row[rrp_price]', '$row[category_id]', '$row[category_name]', '$row[brand_id]', '$row[brand_name]') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE merchant_id = '$row[merchant_id]', merchant_name = '$row[merchant_name]', in_stock = '$row[in_stock]', product_name = '$row[product_name]', aw_deep_link = '$row[aw_deep_link]', aw_image_url = '$row[aw_image_url]', search_price = '$row[search_price]', rrp_price = '$row[rrp_price]', category_id = '$row[category_id]', category_name = '$row[category_name]', brand_id = '$row[brand_id]', brand_name = '$row[brand_name]'");
    $i++;
}
$j = 0;
foreach ($merchants as $row)
{
    mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO merchants (merchant_id, merchant_name) VALUES ('$row[merchant_id]', '$row[merchant_name]') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE merchant_name = '$row[merchant_name]'");
    $j++;
}
echo 'Update complete!<br />' . $i . ' product(s) in total<br />' . $j . ' merchant(s) in total';
mysqli_close($con);
```

My problem is that it seems to be hit or miss whether or not the script will run, first time, every time without receding the following message:

> "PHP Warning:  XMLReader::open(): HTTP request failed!"

And

> "PHP Warning:  XMLReader::open(): Unable to open source data"

This centres around the size of the XML-file. If I try to download a large one (10,000 rows), this error is almost guaranteed. If smaller (6,000 rows), it's usually fine.

I switched to XML Reader from SimpleXML deliberately because of the size of the file thinking XML Reader would not time out (effectively).

I have tried the following:

1. Inserting `set_time_limit(0);` at the start of the file.
2. Removing additional code such as update scripts etc.

Is anyone able to explain to me what is actually happening with this error (is it size, is it memory etc). And, of course, how do I resolve this?

Comment: Do you first download the file and then operate on the local copy?

Comment: No... Should I? @hakre

Comment: Sure. Or: Don't wonder about the error message if not. :) For creating temporary files, this might be helpful: http://php.net/tempnam ; http://php.net/sys_get_temp_dir

Comment: So, just so I understand correctly; if I save the file locally (unzipped) and use the same code as I already have pointed to the temp file - I won't get this error anymore, regardless of the size of the XML doc? @hakre

Comment: Try that, yes. At least if you have XML on your own disk you can actually see that it is XML. And you should not see any "HTTP request failed!" errors if you open a file from disk, too. However you might see those when you download the file. So no magic here, just putting failure-cases apart.